# Getting a syntax error, unexpected end of file error but cant seem to find error

Tags: php

I keep getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file error at line 167. I have gone through this code many times and can't seem to find what I'm missing. I've checked all of the brackets and statements and don't find anything off. Can the error possibly be from the

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -d display_errors=STDOUT
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 


$time_stamp = time();


$disp = $_GET['time_stamp'];
if($disp == "previous")
    $time_stamp -= 43200;
else if($disp == "next")
    $time_stamp += 43200;


$today = date("D, F j, Y, g:i a",$time_stamp);
$start_hour_offset = -3;
$end_hour = 12; 


$table = "event_table";
$field1 = "person";
$field2 = "time";
$field3 = "event_title";
$field4 = "event_message";

try
{

 $db = new SQLite3('dbalexmf14.db');
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
 echo '<p>There was an error connecting to the
database!</p>';
 if ($db)
 {
 echo $exception->getMessage();
 }

}


/**function get_events($name, $ts){


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = $name, time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $a_events= $title. " ". $message;
}**/
function get_hour_string($time_stamp){
$hour = date("g", $time_stamp);
$am_or_pm = date("a",$time_stamp);
return "$hour.00$am_or_pm";
}

print('<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ');
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Calendar</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>Bruin Family Schedule for <?php print"$today" ?> </h1>
<table id="event_table">


<?php
// print the header

print " <tr> \n";
print "     <th class='hr_td_'> &nbsp; </th> <th class='table_header'>Alex</th><th class='table_header'>Ashton</th><th class='table_header'>Joshua</th> \n";
print " </tr> \n";


for ($i=0; $i<=$end_hour;++$i)
    {

    $hour_string = get_hour_string($time_stamp + $i*3600);


    if ($i%2 == 0){

        print "<tr class='even_row'>\n";
        print "<td class='hr_td'>$hour_string</td> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td></td>\n";

    }
    if ($i%2 !=0){

        print "<tr class='odd_row'>\n";
        print "<td class='hr_td'>$hour_string</td> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td>\n";

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = 'Alex', time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $a_events="";
    $j_events="";
    $ah_events="";
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $a_events= $title. " ". $message;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = 'Ashton', time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $ah_events= $title. " ". $message;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = 'Joshua', time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $j_events= $title. " ". $message;
        //$a_events = get_events("Alex", $time_stamp);
        //$ah_events = get-events("Ashton", $time_stamp);
        //$j_events = get_events("Joshua", $time_stamp);
        print "<td>$a_events</td><td>$j_events</td><td>$ah_events</td>";

        print " </tr> \n";

 ?>

</table>

<div>

<form id="prev" method="get" action="calendar2.php">
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="time_stamp" value='previous' />
    <input type="submit" value="Previous"/>
    </p>
</form>

<form id="next" method="get" action="calendar2.php">
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="time_stamp" value='next' />
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </p>
</form>

<form id="today" method="get" action="calendar2.php">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Today"/>
    </p>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which line is 167?

Comment: format your code properly you will automatically find missing brackets

Comment: If you use a decent IDE, then hovering the cursor over a bracket or quote will find its partner - except for one of them

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not properly closed the curly braces in your code.
Try Following

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 


$time_stamp = time();


$disp = $_GET['time_stamp'];
if($disp == "previous")
    $time_stamp -= 43200;
else if($disp == "next")
    $time_stamp += 43200;


$today = date("D, F j, Y, g:i a",$time_stamp);
$start_hour_offset = -3;
$end_hour = 12; 


$table = "event_table";
$field1 = "person";
$field2 = "time";
$field3 = "event_title";
$field4 = "event_message";

try
{

 $db = new SQLite3('dbalexmf14.db');
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
 echo '<p>There was an error connecting to the
database!</p>';
 if ($db)
 {
 echo $exception->getMessage();
 }

}


/**function get_events($name, $ts){


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = $name, time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $a_events= $title. " ". $message;
}**/
function get_hour_string($time_stamp){
$hour = date("g", $time_stamp);
$am_or_pm = date("a",$time_stamp);
return "$hour.00$am_or_pm";
}

print('<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ');
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Calendar</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>Bruin Family Schedule for <?php print"$today" ?> </h1>
<table id="event_table">


<?php


print " <tr> \n";
print "     <th class='hr_td_'> &nbsp; </th> <th class='table_header'>Alex</th><th class='table_header'>Ashton</th><th class='table_header'>Joshua</th> \n";
print " </tr> \n";


for ($i=0; $i<=$end_hour;++$i)
    {

    $hour_string = get_hour_string($time_stamp + $i*3600);


    if ($i%2 == 0){

        print "<tr class='even_row'>\n";
        print "<td class='hr_td'>$hour_string</td> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td></td>\n";

    }
    if ($i%2 !=0){

        print "<tr class='odd_row'>\n";
        print "<td class='hr_td'>$hour_string</td> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td>\n";

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = 'Alex', time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $a_events="";
    $j_events="";
    $ah_events="";
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $a_events= $title. " ". $message;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = 'Ashton', time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $ah_events= $title. " ". $message;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person = 'Joshua', time = $ts || time <= $ts + 3600";
    print "$sql";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($record=$result->fetchArray())
    { $title = $record['event_title'];
    $message = $record['event_message'];
    $j_events= $title. " ". $message;
        //$a_events = get_events("Alex", $time_stamp);
        //$ah_events = get-events("Ashton", $time_stamp);
        //$j_events = get_events("Joshua", $time_stamp);
        print "<td>$a_events</td><td>$j_events</td><td>$ah_events</td>";

        print " </tr> \n";
    }
    }
    }
 ?>

</table>

<div>

<form id="prev" method="get" action="calendar2.php">
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="time_stamp" value='previous' />
    <input type="submit" value="Previous"/>
    </p>
</form>

<form id="next" method="get" action="calendar2.php">
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="time_stamp" value='next' />
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </p>
</form>

<form id="today" method="get" action="calendar2.php">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Today"/>
    </p>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```